# Get elements to align

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on some black boards on my website and sometimes the content isn't the same size in each black board.

so what I've currently got is as following:

[image]

Achieved this by using the following code:

```
var biggestHeight = 0;
$('.board .content').each(function(){
    if(biggestHeight === 0) biggestHeight = $(this).height();
    if(biggestHeight < $(this).height()) bigghestHeight = $(this).height();
});
biggestHeight = biggestHeight + 15;
$('.board .content').css({
    "height" : biggestHeight + "px",
});
```

I want the boards to be like this: but I want the boards to be different sizes depending on the content size, however I want the boards to be aligned at the bottom behind the grass like the first picture.

[image]

Simple example to reproduce the problem (Not exactly reproduced):

```css
.board{
  display: inline-block;
  background: gray;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
#boards-container{
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}
#boards-container .boards{
  position: absolute
}
```

```html
<div id="boards-container">
  <div class="boards">
      <div class="board">
        <p>1st Event</p>
        <p>2nd Event</p>
        <p>3rd Event 3rd Event 3rd Event 3rd Event 3rd Event</p>
      </div>
      <div class="board">
        (This should align at bottom)
        <p>1st News</p>
      </div>
      <div class="board">
        (This should align at bottom)
        <p>1st Gallery</p>
        <p>2nd Gallery</p>
        <p>3rd Gallery</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**NEED ANSWER TO WORK IN IE9+ aswell**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like @Hash 's answer more but here's a non-flexbox version just in case.

Downside is it requires extra wrapper div for each board

```css
.board{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  background: gray;
  width: 30%;
  margin-top:auto;
  
}
#boards-container{
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}
#boards-container .boards{
  position: absolute
}

.wrap{
  margin-left: 5px;
  display:inline-block;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="boards-container">
  <div class="boards">
      <div class="board">
        <div class="wrap">
          <p>1st Event</p>
          <p>2nd Event</p>
          <p>3rd Event 3rd Event 3rd Event 3rd Event 3rd Event</p>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="board">
        <div class="wrap">
          (This should align at bottom)
          <p>1st News</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="board">
       <div class="wrap">
          (This should align at bottom)
          <p>1st Gallery</p>
          <p>2nd Gallery</p>
          <p>3rd Gallery</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To align you can use `flex` with `flex-end` to align at the bottom of the container. More about [flex align](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/align-content/)

```css
.boards {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.board {
  display: inline-block;
  background: gray;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#boards-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}

#boards-container .boards {
  position: absolute
}
```

```html
<div id="boards-container">
  <div class="boards">
    <div class="board">
      <p>1st Event</p>
      <p>2nd Event</p>
      <p>3rd Event 3rd Event 3rd Event 3rd Event 3rd Event</p>
    </div>
    <div class="board">
      (This should align at bottom)
      <p>1st News</p>
    </div>
    <div class="board">
      (This should align at bottom)
      <p>1st Gallery</p>
      <p>2nd Gallery</p>
      <p>3rd Gallery</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Flex doesn't work in IE9+ does it? have you got any other ideas?

Comment: @Chris https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox. Hash, I really don't understand why you align them to `flex-end` when the proper layout action here is to make them equal, which would be: `align-items: stretch`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your overall desired outcome.
It might be as simple as setting some css on those boards - position:absolute and bottom:0

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not a perfect solution as it does not work in Internet Explorer.
Just a different approach towards the problem using CSS grid.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns:  repeat(3, 140px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat( 4, 70px);
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.box {
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
}


.a {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  align-self: stretch;
}

.b {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  align-self: end;
}

.c {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  align-self: stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a">
    <p>1st Event</p>
    <p>2nd Event</p>
    <p>3rd Event 3rd Event 3rd Event 3rd Event 3rd Event</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box b">
    (This should align at bottom)
          <p>1st News</p>       
  </div>
  <div class="box c">
    (This should align at bottom)
      <p>1st Gallery</p>
      <p>2nd Gallery</p>
      <p>3rd Gallery</p>
  </div>
</div>
```